# C# OAuth Bearer Token - "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters

Tags: c#, base64, bearer-token

"The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."

I am getting Bearer token which I am trying to apply Convert.FromBase64String(string) but I am getting  The input is not a valid Base-64 string... string

My bearer Token is as follow :

"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6ImFpbV9hcGlvYXV0aGRpdCJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6WyJSUzQwMWsvRW1wbG95ZWUvQmVuZWZpY2lhcnkiXSwiZXhwIjoxNjk1ODgzMDYwLCJqdGkiOiI5ODhjNjcxYS0wMzhlLTRkMTMtYjYzOS1hMGY4YmI3N2VlMDYiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiI1ZDE3MGFjOS1jZDY2LTQxNWYtODMzYS02Nzc2NDMwOTc5MjgifQ.SL3AC06E-OLB2yYmCQsOXdzFjeF2-R271QWswzCiEl_U77el6iWvfCQ2GxeBB2-AjVVJ-5gxiu0LI9sTgucK9Xhjnx5W_ZVQgzr_XSa2QcEIGXT5BH1a7OIEd7XTZT6WWwtzcA4QB5vXamA7KcWhxP1TeqrAl2Vd0AE-JagVS1FIHt70BLiqy21z_fsL4J4sE6gxVn8R5g9Djjy-UsH64anIgEZzrLbbDqP6AbSPLJIqpEq8T7W8ee8KGps2Z-IKg4XRv1_JqYPo4f_Qj21b8bpGp5DzifKu3UF9hrInAS9OxC8e1ZW5jesXiux62oWe7gHAay37m_4sEu0JNrbd_g"

I tried replacing - with + and _ with /and added padding ==

but still fails at Convert.FromBase64String(s);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not decode JWT payload from base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62111548/could-not-decode-jwt-payload-from-base64)

Comment: 1) you can't decode the whole token at once, it consists of 3 parts separated by a `.` and you need to split the token first. 2) *and added padding ==* - you can't just blindly add "==". Base64 needs 0, 1 or 2 padding characters, so that the resulting string has a length that is a multiple of 4.